# Is there any property for Google API Key in gmlib?

Tags: delphi, gmlib

I tried gmlib with Delphi 2010 and I'm very happy about it's functionality.

Is there any property for Google API Key?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would help considerably if you explain what "library" you're referring to, so we have some context to go on. (And also so people in the future searching here have some content to view to see if it helps them find a solution.) Can you [edit] to make it more clear what you're asking?

Comment: @KenWhite Question is tagged `gmlib`

Comment: Lefteris, I edited your question to make it a bit more clear what library you're using. But you still need to edit it to clarify what you're really asking and why.

Comment: Into the [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) I don't find any property to specify the Google Maps API Key. If you know what it is, tell me please

Comment: @JerryDodge: I'm aware. :-) The question is still too vague. If I tag a question "Delphi" and say "What property can I set that makes something active?", it's still not a clear question despite the tag. Adding a tag does not automatically mean the question has sufficient detail, and the OP should edit to add more details.

Comment: Yes , it is my first question on StackOverflow and probably I don't know the rules. @KenWhite : I mean gmlib library for Delphi.

Comment: @KenWhite Indeed, did you read my second comment before or after you responded?

Comment: @JerryDodge: I simply responded to your comment. I wanted to let you know that I am quite capable of seeing what tags exist on a question. :-) I'm also fairly adept at reading the words in the question most of the time, especially when there are so few of them like in this one. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't. It doesn't use a key. If you want to use yours, you'll have to edit *map.html*, where Google's JavaScript is linked in. Refer to [Google's instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld) for how to add your API key to the URL.

Comment: I don't know that, thanks. If you changes the map.html, you need to recompile the resources (use rc.cmd) and then recompile the components.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Yes , that is the solution until cadetill release a new version. Thank you !